# connecting to MongoDB replica set with monk in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin, monk

when I do this in monk

```
var monk = require('monk')
var db = monk('10.25.125.20/mydb')
```

it works fine, but when I do this

```
var monk = require('monk')
var db = monk('10.25.125.20/mydb,10.25.125.22')
```

it throws an error with the message: "database names cannot contain the character '.' "
what am I doing wrong?

The IP addresses, are computers in my LAN, running the MongoDB instances, configured as a replica set, they are actually three nodes, but the third is an arbiter

this is what is what goes out to stderr

```
/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:233
    if(databaseName.indexOf(invalidChars[i]) != -1) throw new Error("database 
                                                          ^
Error: database names cannot contain the character '.'
    at validateDatabaseName (/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:233:59)
    at new Db (/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:95:3)
    at connectFunction (/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:243:29)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:313:5)
    at SkinClass.SkinDb._open (/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/db.js:36:25)
    at SkinClass.open (/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongoskin/lib/utils.js:162:14)
    at new Manager (/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/lib/manager.js:65:15)
    at Manager (/home/user/Dev/project2/node_modules/monk/lib/manager.js:32:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Dev/project2/config/mongo.js:18:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node js / MongoDB replica set array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19666210/1202461)

Comment: I am doing exactly, what is recommended on that post, but I am still getting the same error!

Comment: It seems to work when I change from  

 `var db = monk('10.25.125.20/mydb,10.25.125.22')`

to  

 `var db = monk('mongo://10.25.125.20/mydb,mongo://10.25.125.22')`  

let me see if everything works well downstream

Comment: I can't test it, but, according to my link, it should be something like `monk('10.25.125.20,10.25.125.22/mydb?replicaSet=[replicaSet Name]')`

Answer (score 0):

DB Name and set ID at the end:

```
mongodb://10.25.125.20:portnr,10.25.125.22:portnr/mydb?replicaSet=<rsname>
```